# Method oveloading - Object vs Object vararg

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

See the code below:

```
// 1st method
private static void method(Object o){
    System.out.println("object method");
}
// 2nd method
private static void method(Object... o){
    System.out.println("object vararg method");
}
public static void main(String [] ar){
    method(null); // 1st call
    Integer value=null; 
    method(value); // 2nd call
}
```

I expected `1st call` and `2nd call` both should invoke `1st method`, thought `null` will prefer to match `Object` than `Object...` vararg. But I am wrong.

- `1st call` invoked `2nd method`
- `2nd call` invoked `1st method`

My question is why or how `null` matches to `Object...` vararg and not `Object` in my code?

Comment: So just to check, you're asking about the *first* call here, not the second? It's easier to only explain overload resolution about a single call...

Comment: Object is less specific than Object[]. Varags is essentially Object[].

Comment: What is `Object...` is it an array of `Object`s or is it a subclass of `Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JLS 15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) explains this exact scenario:

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting** boxing or unboxing conversion, **or the use of variable arity method invocation**. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of the introduction of variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or unboxing. However, the declaration of a variable arity method (§8.4.1) can change the method chosen for a given method method invocation expression, because **a variable arity method is treated as a fixed arity method in the first phase. For example, declaring m(Object...) in a class which already declares m(Object) causes m(Object) to no longer be chosen for some invocation expressions (such as m(null)), as m(Object[]) is more specific**.

Comment: Did you seriously re-open a closed duplicate just to add your own answer?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I re-opened it since the supposed duplicate answer you linked this question to didn't answer this question at all. And since I just found a reference in the JLS that explains this behavior, I opened it and posted an answer.

Comment: And on top of that the other given answer is wrong in this case.

Comment: @DennisIch In what way is it wrong? Granted it doesn't address the first and second phase resolution that is explained here, but it still explains the basic "match the most specific signature, if possible" logic.

Comment: Well wrong is maybe the wrong word but it does not really answer the question in this specific null case and only provides some brief explanation for the general case which has its value but i think this one is the correct answer and therefore good he reopened it.

Despite i think we should not discuss the other answer under this one.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Object...` is essentially `Object[]` and since `null` is a valid `Object[]`, it will match to the most specific one.

If you had 3 methods with first having `Object` parameter, the second having `SubClass` param and the last having `SubSubClass` param, the last one would be chosen.

Whereas if you add a method with a `String` parameter to your original code, you will get a compile time error, since there is no longer a single most specific match for `null`.

Comment: I'd say that the `null` value is implicitly convertible to `Object[]` - if you use `instanceof` itself, that will fail.

Comment: Overload resolution between Foo(Object) and Foo(String) is perfectly possible: the latter will be chosen.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Not if he adds it to his example code, which already has a method with a subclass of `Object` as a parameter.

Comment: I think `null` can refer to either, and the warning from Eclipse reads : 

The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to `Object[]` for the invocation of the varargs method `method(Object...)` from type `TestClass`. It could alternatively be cast to `Object` for a varargs invocation.

Comment: lars@lars-laptop:~/Documents$ javac Test.java 
`Test.java:11: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
    method(null); // 1st call
           ^
  cast to Object for a varargs call
  cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
1 warning`

Comment: @Gyanapriya No, null can't refer to either one, since it would cause a compile time error for ambiguity instead of a warning.